# How to add Onload change event in Dropdown list

Tags: javascript, data-view-web-part, dropdown

Onload of the page:
1. Change the selected value of dropdown
2. DFWP will update list

I have a dropdown list connected to a DFWP for filtering.
Using javascript and onload function of SharePoint, I would like to pick a dropdown menu option using:

```
setSelectedIndex2(document.getElementById("ctl00_PlaceHolderTopNavBar_DropDownList1"),"General");
```

default menu option is "**Brand**": the option shows another list

I want to change the DFWP default value to **General** using js

```
_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("MyFunctionName");

function MyFunctionName()
 {
    $('#ctl00_PlaceHolderTopNavBar_DropDownList1').change(test).change();
 {
 function test()
 {
    $( "#ctl00_PlaceHolderTopNavBar_DropDownList1" ).change(function() 
    {  
       setSelectedIndex2(document.getElementById("ctl00_PlaceHolderTopNavBar_DropDownList1"),"General");
    });
});
```

result of this script:
The page reload non stop and keeps executing the **test** function.

Hope you can help me with this. Thanks

Comment: You only want to trigger the change() when the current value is not equal to `General`. You are now performing the change on every pageload

Comment: Yes. I am changing the list depending on the user information extracted from the active directory. I even use a `__doPostBack('ctl00_PlaceHolderTopNavBar_DropDownList','');`, . same result. Page keeps reloading